# What is the thought process and method to be used to decide where to post question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am seeking to sharpen my understanding of published data.   It is not a programming question nor does it seem to fit nicely in other categories.  What is the thought process and method to decide where to post the question?

## QUESTION

> ORD reporting shows 2017 January revenue passenger as 4,501,484:
>
> https://www.flychicago.com/SiteColl...actAndFigures/AirTraffic/0117
>   ORD SUMMARY.pdf
>
> Is this number calculated by summing all revenue passengers on
>   arriving flights and all revenue passengers on departing flights?
>
> I would like to understand that if a person is transiting through ORD
>   (person may or may not switch aircraft): does that count as '2
>   passengers' counting method or 0?
>
> I ask the questions because I would like to understand if it is
>   possible to understand of the 4.5M, is there a thought process to
>   determine how many of these passengers required TSA security
>   screening?
>
> What exactly triggers the counter revenue passenger? Is it a revenue
>   ticket that originates from ORD? Originates or terminates in ORD? Any
>   references are appreciated.

## Update

Question was posted to open-data because data-science labeled the questions off-topic and travel moderators have shutdown similar questions in the past.

[Airport Passenger Data Interpretation](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13273/airport-passenger-data-interpretation)

Comment: If you're not sure, ask a [tag:site-recommendation] question here, which you did.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog  Post this response as an 'Answer'?

Comment: This question as it stands is too broad, as you're asking two questions: "how to figure out where to post a question" and "where to post this question".

Answer (score 4):

Think about what your question is. In this case it looks like you are asking about travel procedures, so should probably be asked on Travel.

Always distill your answer to its basics, then look at the range of Stack Exchange sites. They all have a scope, so you should be able to identify the best one.

If you do get it wrong, don't worry - someone will help migrate it to a better site.

Comment: Don't believe that this is on-topic for Travel. Also, a moderator may need to be involved if the right site isn't in the list of available sites for normal users to vote for.

Comment: There are already similar questions on Travel, @Sonic

Comment: That was my initial thought: I have asked similar questions on travel only to have them quickly closed for being off topic: it seems they favor questions of the format: How does one .... when traveling?

Comment: @gatorback - offtopic is actually quite a broad group of close reasons. What I always do on a site I am unfamiliar with is read the full About page and on-topic list, and then check out some examples.